# php Regex - Pattern incorrect not getting desired results

Tags: php, regex

I have a file that I am reading, and searching the entire file for a certain pattern.  Here's sample line:

`DATA "1354236384craan18p.1354236392craan18p.1354668684AR_ESCALATORCase HD0347023 was automatically closed on 5/12/2012 1:51:24 p.m.." "IT Services | File Services | Recovery"`

What I want is to create regex that gives me the `"IT Services | File Services | Recovery"`
section only.

I have the following Regex and code but does not work - any ideas?

```
$whole_wk_file = file_get_contents('Work.arx');

$pattern1 = '/\"[^\"\|]+\|[^\"\|]+\|[^\"\|]+\"/';

preg_match_all($pattern1, $whole_wk_file, $matches_wk, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r($matches_wk{0});
```

Again this is in PHP.

Comment: And how did you come up with the regex you have now? Doesn't seem very targeted at your specific sample.

Comment: will this always be in the "string | string | string" format?

Comment: Hi, if I use \"[^\"\|]+\|[^\"\|]+\|[^\"\|]+\" in an online regex tester it works but not in my php wamp environment

Comment: Hi Kelly - yes always in that format, no numbers

Comment: Not sure if Im escaping correctly

Comment: This runs perfectly for me using just the sample text you provided..

Comment: its running on php 5.2.6 perfectly. user1871114 Can you check whether you are getting the file content. print_r($whole_wk_file);

Comment: I can't possibly be getting the file content since I'm not on your system.. I've replaced the file_get_contents with a string containing your data string you provided.

Comment: as far as I can tell this should work on php 5. for some reason when I run it in php 4 the PREG_PATTERN_ORDER doesn't seem to be followed. The only other issue I can think of is if your file uses a multibyte encoding such as utf-8

Comment: HI Kasun - Yes print_r($whole_wk_file) works

Comment: File is here not sure if using utf-8 [link](http://itssd.otago.ac.nz/dev/agent_stats/work_test.arx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, fortunately it seems php's multibyte functions supports Windows-1252 character encoding. This is what I have come up with.. Hope this works

```
$whole_wk_file = file_get_contents('Work.arx');

$pattern1 = '/\"[^\"\|]+\|[^\"\|]+\|[^\"\|]+\"/';

mb_internal_encoding("Windows-1252");
mb_eregi($pattern1, $whole_wk_file, $matches_wk);

print_r($matches_wk);
```

Comment: ok so using your regex, it returns nothing, just not sure when using http://www.infobyip.com/regularexpressioncalculator.php and regex - \"[^\"\|]+\|[^\"\|]+\|[^\"\|]+\" using data from file [File](http://itssd.otago.ac.nz/dev/agent_stats/work_test.arx) works. I think that the file type is the issue - any idea's ?

Comment: Thanks for your help greatly appreciated - not sure what is going on here

Comment: Your problem is the character set.. I've opened the file using a text editor and at the very top it says CHAR-SET windows-1252

Comment: Let me do some checking and see what I can find;

Comment: There, I've update my answer so that it is appropriate for your files character encoding. Hope this helps :)

Comment: File encoding is not the issue either.. After uploading you file to my server and using your code you provided exactly it seems to work just fine.. Not sure what to tell you.. You can see your code at work [here](http://coplay.dyndns.org:9999/~kel/testbed/regtest.php). This is your exact code running on the file you uploaded..

Comment: Hi Kelly -Thanks alot for your help, just to clarify are you using the exact code that I uploaded in the first question ? If it is my system setup - im stumped

Comment: yes, this is your exact code. The only thing I can think of is that your file_get_contents is failing giving $whole_wk_file the value false and then you are running your regx on false instead of a string. Normally a warning would be raised if the file does not exist but if this system is set up for production it may have error reporting turned off so it doesn't spit out warnings and notices to users. I would start by inserting a check to make sure $whole_wk_file has a usable string value. Maybe even use error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top of the script to make sure you are seeing ALL of issues.

Comment: Cheers Kelly, I think the file_get_contents is failing as I read line by line instead and this works fine - Thanks for all your help - appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your regex

```
'/"(([^"|]+\|){1,}[^"]+)"/'
```

The text will be in group 1 of each match or perhaps even just this one

```
'/(?<=")(?:[^"|]+\|){1,}[^"]+(?=")/'
```

which will match without any groups

Comment: That returned alot of data but returned nothing that I could use, is it possible to say only 2 | and no numbers between two quotes ?

Comment: These two regexes definitely work using the data sample you've given. My guess is that you have some inconsistencies between your file content and what you've given above (as Kelly Copley has mentioned it could be an encoding issue)

Comment: How can i force simple encoding when reading froma file in php ?

Comment: on each and every line there is the part that i want to extract - at the end of the line, between 2 double quotes, and only that part.

Comment: I do notice that the output file has EOT, ETX, when reading in Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems to find all the matches you want, but I also get a false positive on a quoted section that happens to contain exactly two pipes (`|`).  You said in a comment that every match should be at the end of its enclosing line line, so adding an anchor should take care of that problem:

```
'/"[^"|]+\|[^"|]+\|[^"|]+"[ ]*$/m'
```

The `m` modifier empowers the `$` anchor to match at line boundaries, and the `[ ]*` is there because every line of your file seems to end with a space character.  I could have used `\s*` instead, but that would match the newlines as well as spaces.  Then it would have to give them right back so the anchor (`$`) can do its job.  In that spirit, it might be worth your while to exclude newlines entirely:

```
'/"[^"|\r\n]+\|[^"|\r\n]+\|[^"|\r\n]+"[ ]*$/m'
```

I also got rid of a bunch of unnecessary backslashes.

As for those junk characters, I think [Kelly Copley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812616/php-regex-pattern-incorrect-not-getting-desired-results#comment19006345_13813332) is right, it's not an encoding issue (or if it is, it's too late to fix it).  They don't seem to affect the parts you care about.